# Lost privileges since upgrading to 13.10

Tags: mount, permissions, shutdown, users, privileges

Since upgrading to 13.10, I no longer have the 'privileges' to do the following things:

1. Mount USB/CDROM drives
2. Run software centre or software updater
3. Press the GUI shut down or restart buttons
4. Unlock my account in the 'settings - user accounts' section (padlock is greyed out)

Also, when logging on as a guest user I get error messages relating to Compiz crashing with SIGSEGV and it hangs on a blank wallpaper screen.

However, I still am able to use sudo in the terminal.

Output of 'groups' is

```
jenchris adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev lpadmin admin pulse pulse-access sambashare
```

`sudo usermod -U username` doesn't have any effect

Comment: Same problem as this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/68793/how-do-i-unlock-a-user-account?rq=1 but none of the suggested fixes there worked, eg I tried sudo usermod -U username but no change.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the GUI apps talk to policykit & consolekit over dbus.  There is also a requirement that you login from a 'modern' display manager like lightdm or gdm and not xdm or from a tty (and user startx/xinit).  Make sure you have all the relevant policykit & consolekit packages installed and that dbus is running properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this answer was very helpful to me when hitting the same problem after upgrading to 13.10. A simple `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selecting `lightdm` as default window manager did the trick for me.